# Oracle Data Migration best usage in isolated servers

Tags: oracle, data-migration

I am looking for the best way to migrate data from one oracle database to another. Both databases are placed in isolated servers and unable to make direct connection between those databases.

Comment: Does your migration involve Data Transformation?

Comment: Yes it has data conversion.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, we first did a Data Pump from the Source Database to the Destination Database using a Different Schema and Table Name (i.e. *_SRC).
We then prepared a Mapping Table and a simple program to Transform the Data Sets from the Source to the Destination Tables.
After running the program and doing the needed validations, we proceeded to unload the "_SRC" objects and schema to free up some tablespace.

Comment: As I explained we do not have direct  connection, so we can not connect those schema. Finally we decided to migration data using CSV file.